# Dropdown select menu in css only

Tags: css

I want to do the following:

I want to build a select menu but I have no Bootstrap, if I had, I would have done so with `btn-groups` and such.

I need to do so using pure css if possible, but I have a slight problem.

Im using angular.js in my front end, and if a select menu is open, I want to close it not only when click on an item inside it, but with any click on the screen (not whithin the window of the items and such),

How can I do this without any ugly jquery code? pure angular?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100344/pure-css-multi-level-drop-down-menu

Comment: http://cssdeck.com/labs/another-simple-css3-dropdown-menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is inherantly tricky to due purely in CSS, in real world use cases you will want to implement a solution utilising JS.

However, nothing is impossible!*

### [Pure CSS Select Menu](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/sjf6eeyj/)

HTML

```
<ul tabindex='0'>
    <li>
        <input id='item1' type='radio' name='item' checked='true' />
        <label for='item1'>Item 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input id='item2' type='radio' name='item' />
        <label for='item2'>Item 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input id='item3' type='radio' name='item' />
        <label for='item3'>Item 3</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul, li {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li input {
    display:none;
}
ul:not(:focus) input:not(:checked), ul:not(:focus) input:not(:checked) + label {
    display:none;
}
input:checked+label {
    color:red;
}
```

<sup>*Unfortunately, you just cant get all the functionality you want...but (I believe) its as close as you'll get in CSS alone</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This css will kinda get rid of a lot of standard browser stuff, and maybe give you a good starting point for building a pure css 'bootstrap-ish' select menu.

```
select{
padding:3px;
margin: 0;
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
-moz-border-radius:4px;
border-radius:4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
background: #f8f8f8;
color:#888;
border:none;
outline:none;
display: inline-block;
-webkit-appearance:none;
-moz-appearance:none;
appearance:none;
cursor:pointer;
```

}