# multi-level (drop down) menu css js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have multi-level (drop down) menu, **such that I can change the menu just one file, and do not have to go to every single page to change the menu. I will need three level menu**.

I have modified someone code but not working as I like

CSS code (OurSite.css)

```
ul#third-level-menu
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -150px;
  width: 150px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul#third-level-menu > li
{
  height: 30px;
  background: #999999;
}

ul#third-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

ul#second-level-menu
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul#second-level-menu > li
{
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  background: #999999;
}
ul#second-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

ul#top-level-menu
{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul#top-level-menu > li
{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #999999;
}
ul#top-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

ul#top-level-menu li:hover > ul
{
/* On hover, display the next level's menu */
display: inline;
}


/* Menu Link Styles */

ul#top-level-menu a /* Apply to all links inside the multi-level menu */
{
  font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;

/* Make the link cover the entire list item-container */
  display: block;
  line-height: 30px;
}

ul#top-level-menu a:hover { color: #000000; }
```

I also have 
js code (Menu-Script.js)

```
document.getElementById("nav01").innerHTML =
"<ul id='top-level-menu'>" +
"<li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>" +

"<ul id='second-level-menu'>" +
"<li><a href='index12.html'>Home12</a></li>" +


 "<ul id='third-level-menu'>" +
 "<li><a href='index123.html'>Home123</a></li>" +
 "<li><a href='index124.html'>Home124</a></li>" +
 "</ul>" +

 "<li><a href='index13.html'>Home13</a></li>" +

 "</ul>"  +

"<li><a href='customers.html'>Data</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='about.html'>About</a></li>" +
"</ul>";
```

For HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Demo</title>
  <link href="OurSite.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <nav id="nav01"></nav>
  <div id="main">
    <h1>Welcome to Our Site</h1>
    <h2>Web Site Main Ingredients:</h2>

    <p>Pages (HTML)</p>
    <p>Style (CSS)</p>
    <p>Code (JavaScript)</p>
  </div>
  <script src="Menu-Script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Or if you have a better code pleaes let me know, many thanks

Comment: http://cssmenumaker.com/builder/5435486 , visit this site, you can create your own multilevel menu

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100344/pure-css-multi-level-drop-down-menu

Are you looking for something like that?  That might be a start.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm... your code is not best, but, i think you only change the html inside js:

```
document.getElementById("nav01").innerHTML =
"<ul id='top-level-menu'>" +
"<li><a href='index.html'>Home</a>" + // not close li here

"<ul id='second-level-menu'>" +
"<li><a href='index12.html'>Home12</a>" + // not close li here


 "<ul id='third-level-menu'>" +
 "<li><a href='index123.html'>Home123</a></li>" +
 "<li><a href='index124.html'>Home124</a></li>" +
 "</ul></li>" + // close li here

 "<li><a href='index13.html'>Home13</a></li>" +

 "</ul></li>"  + // close li here

"<li><a href='customers.html'>Data</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='about.html'>About</a></li>" +
"</ul>";
```

Insert `<ul>` inside his parent `<li>`.

```
[ul] 
 -> li 
    [ul]
     -> li 
        [ul] 
         -> li
         -> li
 -> li
 -> li
```

Example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/9tok0z5d/

Comment: I have tested it works well in Chrome and FireFox, but not IE11.  If you know how to solve this.  Appreciated.