# select tag under select tag

Tags: html, css

How can I make something like this?[This is a sample image of the output I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMOxD.jpg) Thanks in advance. Just starting to learn new things

```
<form>
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3
        <select>
            <option value="3.1">3.1</option>
            <option value="3.2">3.2</option>
        </select>
    </option>
</select></form>
```

Comment: no you cannot by nesting select like this

Comment: You cannot do that with selects. What you show in your image looks more like a menu. What you can do this this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup That does come close.

Comment: That is a simple dropdown menu. You can either do it `onclick` using JS, or `:hover` using CSS3. There are plenty of tutorials in the internet, even here on stackoverflow. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100344/pure-css-multi-level-drop-down-menu

Comment: @TemaniAfif Agreed, you need to use lists in order to implement this

Comment: im using select cause i need it in my form submission

Comment: You will be able to do this with lists now with select.

Comment: @1437 Do you want to use Bootstrap? It will make this a lot easier.

Comment: If you need it included in your form submission, then use some JS to handle the form submission. You can't nest selects within one another. This is a great opportunity to take advantage of nest lists though.

Comment: can you show me how to do it? thanks